# Why does one .get_rect() call throw an error while the other doesn't?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I've just started with python and pygame and I got an Attribute error in a `get_rect()` method despite the previous `get_rect()` method having no problems.

```py
import pygame
import sys
import os

#Current working directory.
print(os.getcwd())

#Does path exist?
print (os.path.exists("D:\Learning Python\Pygame Bootcamp\My Code\The Game\Images"))

filepath = "D:\Learning Python\Pygame Bootcamp\My Code\The Game\Images"

#Locations for the images.
grassDir = os.path.join(filepath,"grass.png")
ballDir = os.path.join(filepath,"ball.png")
characterBodyDir = os.path.join(filepath,"characterBody.png")
characterFootDir = os.path.join(filepath,"characterFoot.png")


#Initializes PyGame.
pygame.init()

#Defining the display dimensions.
width = 900
height = 700
screenDim = (width, height)

#Initializes a window or screen for display with defined dimensions.
#.set_mode needs to have a tuple.
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screenDim)

#Sets window title.
pygame.display.set_caption("The Game")

#Loads the image.
#".convert()" loads the image into a pygame object called a surface.
#It makes there pixel values the same. Makes loading the image faster.
grassImage = pygame.image.load(grassDir).convert()
#Transforms the image. In this case, it scales the image to the screen dimensions.
grassImage = pygame.transform.scale(grassImage,(width, height))
#A rescale factor. Adjust to adjust scale of all images.
rescale = 3

#Player
player = pygame.image.load(characterBodyDir).convert_alpha()
#".get_rect()" Takes an attribute from the surface object.
playerWidth = player.get_rect().width
playerHeight = player.get_rect().height
#Rescaling
player = pygame.transform.scale(player,(playerWidth * rescale, playerHeight * rescale))
#pygame.transform.rotate() rotates COUNTER-CLOCKWISE.
player = pygame.transform.rotate(player,90)

#Foot
foot = pygame.image.load(characterFootDir).convert_alpha
footWidth = foot.get_rect().width
footHeight = foot.get_rect().height
foot = pygame.transform.scale(foot,(footWidth * rescale,footHeight * rescale))
foot = pygame.transform.rotate(foot,90)

#Draws image to screen, takes image and position as input.
screen.blit(grassImage,(0,0))
screen.blit(player,(0,0))
screen.blit(foot,(0,0))

#Tells if the game is finished.
finished = False


#Start of the game loop.
while finished == False:
    #Processing all the events:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #Do things in this loop.
        #Quits the game.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                finished = True
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    pygame.display.flip() #Updates the display/load next frame.
```

The error message is this:

```
D:\Learning Python
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Learning Python\Pygame Bootcamp\My Code\The Game\main.py", line 56, in <module>
    footWidth = foot.get_rect().width
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

Could somebody please help? As far as I can see, `playerWidth` and `footWidth` should be fine but `playerWidth` is while `footWidth` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call the function the second time:

```py
player = pygame.image.load(characterBodyDir).convert_alpha()
# vs
foot = pygame.image.load(characterFootDir).convert_alpha # missing '()'
```

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.